# Python language/syntax usage

Tags: python

New to python but ran into something I don't understand.  The following line of code:

```
diff = features[0:] - test[0]    # <- this is what I don't get
```

is used thusly:

```
x = diff[i]
```

to return the element-wise difference between `features[i]` and `test[0]`.  Can anyone point to a language reference for this or explain it?  I understand how the result can be developed using "def" or "lambda" but I don't understand the construction.

thanks!

Comment: This looks like it's using NumPy or something similar. Go read the NumPy tutorial, or the documentation for whatever the type of `features` is.

Comment: Nump allows you express basic operations element wise. More [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations).

Answer (score 3):

the answer depends on what `features[0:]` and `test[0]` evaluate to. 
if `test[0]` is a number and `features[0:]` is a numpy array, then you may be using numpy to subtract a number from each element in a list:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> array = numpy.array([49, 51, 53, 56])
>>> array - 13
array([36, 38, 40, 43])
```

Answer (score 2):

`feature` appears to be a [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) array. Numpy arrays 'broadcast' scalar operations to the whole array.

```
import numpy as np
asd = np.full([10,10], 10, np.int64)
asd /= 5
print asd # prints a 10x10 array of 2s
```